# Select multiple cells with a common parents

Tags: css

Currently I'm using the CSS:

```
#myTable > td:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(5), td:nth-child(6), td:nth-child(7), td:nth-child(10), td:nth-child(14), td:nth-child(15), td:nth-child(16) {
    display : none;
}
```

But this just hides the 2nd cell of the table "myTable" and hides "5,6,7..,16" cells of all other tables.

I want to hide "2,5,6,7,..16" cells of "myTable" but not all my tables. What kind of a selector do I use for this?

Comment: You have to add `#myTable >` before every one of the comma separated values. Otherwise that part applies only to the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your problem:

```
#myTable > td:nth-child(2),
#myTable > td:nth-child(5),
#myTable > td:nth-child(6),
#myTable > td:nth-child(7),
#myTable > td:nth-child(10),
#myTable > td:nth-child(14),
#myTable > td:nth-child(15),
#myTable > td:nth-child(16) {
    display : none;
}
```

the `,` is an equivalent of OR so if you not add `#myTable` on each selector, you will not be able to only selected child of `#myTable` element but child of all element.

A don't know what is the place of `#myTable` but this will only work if it is on the parent element, so a `tr` item. Because use `>` is more slow, maybe this is only useful.

```
#myTable td:nth-child(2),
#myTable td:nth-child(5),
#myTable td:nth-child(6),
#myTable td:nth-child(7),
#myTable td:nth-child(10),
#myTable td:nth-child(14),
#myTable td:nth-child(15),
#myTable td:nth-child(16) {
    display : none;
}
```

Alternatively, there are maybe a reason because this td must be not visible so, for example, because there are less important:

```
<table class="my-table">
    <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td class="less-important">Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td class="less-important">Column 5</td>
        <td class="less-important">Column 6</td>
        <td class="less-important">Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td class="less-important">Column 10</td>
        <td>Column 11</td>
        <td>Column 12</td>
        <td>Column 13</td>
        <td class="less-important">Column 14</td>
        <td class="less-important">Column 15</td>
        <td class="less-important">Column 16</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and your CSS could be to only display all column in desktop and hide less important on mobile with a Mobile First method:

```
.my-table .less-important {
    display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .my-table .less-important {
        display: table-cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it does, but I was hoping for a shorter alternative. You have any other approach?